# Excluding files and folders from visual studio intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I want the files in the wwwroot folder not to be processed by Visual Studio intellisense!

I use the following code in MyProject.csproj and the wwwroot folder is ignored by intellisense but the problem is that this command prevents the wwwroot folder from being published too!

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="wwwroot/**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Do you have a solution for Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of this command  `<Content Remove="wwwroot/**" />`  is to exclude this folder at compile time and it does be excluded from this project when publishing. But there is a workaround to include specific folder when publishing.

The `CopyToPublishDirectory` attribute for ItemGroup elements that determines whether to copy the file to the publish directory .

[image]

You can add the following code in your .pubxml file

```
<ItemGroup>               
 <Content Include="your path\WebApplication1\wwwroot\**"  CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You can see the wwwroot is copied to your publish folder after publishing:
[image]

I tested in my web app without adding the code above, my page looks like messy because missing wwwroot folder which contains css file and js file.
[image]

After adding the code above, the page shows normal after publishing.
[image]